Abp IMultiTenant interface issue
When a class inherits from Abp framework IMultiTenant interface, when I run the migration command, the script would set the TenantId nullable to true even I have configure to IsRequired(). This only happens when inheriting from Abp framework IMultiTenant interface, as I have tried to create my own IMultiTenant interface and run the migration again, it would set to nullable to false. Does anyone know how to resolve it?
I'm expecting the TenantId set to nullable to false when inheriting from the IMultiTenant Abp framework.
public class Preference : IMultiTenant
{
    public Guid? TenantId { get; private set; } 
}

public class PreferenceEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Preference>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Preference> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Preferences", Options.Schema);
        builder.Property(x => x.TenantId).IsRequired();
    }
}
TenantId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true)


perhaps set the propertyy to not be nullable, as in you're example it is TenantId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true) change nullable: true to nullable: false

@3dd , that one is generate by ef core.. i have a lot of module having the tenant id, it's hard to change all. plus, i cant change the tenant id with nullable guid as it wont match with the interface.
